# monitor file receiving via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-transfer

I'm now trying to transfer files between Android devices via bluetooth. I already implemented my sender side. I'm not using InputStream/OutputStream. I'm using Intent.ACTION_SEND. Everything in there sender side works fine, but when it comes to the receiver side, I'm facing two problems.

1. There's the pop out notification saying "Do you want to receive this file?". Is there any way I can avoid this thing?
2. How can I know that there's a file coming in and the file transfer is finished or stopped at the receiver side?

It seems that these two problems can be solved using InputStream/OutputStream, but I don't really want to use them. Maybe a listener that monitors Bluetooth, or some functions in BluetoothAdapter/BluetoothDevice can do this?

Thanks for help. My code is like below: (in my MainActivity.java)

```
public void beginBT() {
    if (isSender) {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/log.txt");

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));

        if (!findBluetoothForIntent(intent)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth Not Found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            //intent will send the file via bluetooth
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } else { //receiver side
        //make device be discoverable
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    }
}

public boolean findBluetoothForIntent(Intent intent){
    List appsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    String packageName = null;
    String className = null;

    for (Object info: appsList){
        if (info instanceof ResolveInfo) {
            packageName = ((ResolveInfo) info).activityInfo.packageName;
            if (packageName.equals("com.android.bluetooth")){
                className = ((ResolveInfo) info).activityInfo.name;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (className != null) {
        intent.setClassName(packageName, className);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question is always so much fun!!

1. About the pop out notification, I can't do anything about it, unless I use InStream/OutStream.
2. For the receiver side, use BroadcastReceiver to monitor actions of the device. Here I monitor the disconnecting action of bluetooth. Because there will be a connecting action when the device begin to receive file, and when it finishes, there will be a disconnecting action.

Don't know if the following code would help anybody, :)

`MainActivity.java`

```
private static final String BT_DISCONNECTED = "android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED";
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action == BT_DISCONNECTED) {
            //now file transmitting has finished, can do something to the file
            //if you know the file name, better to check if the file is actually there 
            // - make sure this disconnection not initiated by any other reason.
        }
    }

IntentFileter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

**Warning: remember to unregister this receiver when you exit the activity, or simply when you don't need it**